# как переписать код, что бы он был кликабельным а не при долгом нажатии

Tags: javascript, java, android

```
 holder.itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            menu.add(holder.getAdapterPosition(),0,0,"Принять заявку");
            menu.add(holder.getAdapterPosition(),1,0,"Отменить заявку");

        }


    });
```

Comment: прошу помогите! не могу найти нужной инфы!

Comment: чтобы так же всплывало два окна только при нажатии а не удерживании!

Comment: Исправь вопрос. Под вопросом ссылка "править".

Comment: Написать свой интерфейс для обработки клика на элемент списка